# Properties in Groovy base scripts

Tags: groovy, dsl, groovyshell

I have a DSL where, if present, a closure called `before` will be called before every command.
In my setup I have 3 files: The script itself - `Script`, a `ScriptBase`, that is 'attached' to the script via a `CompilerConfiguration`, and a `Handler`.

In the script I may or may not have a closure called `before`.

```
before = {
    //Do stuff.
}
```

Notice the lack of a type declaration, or `def`. If I understand Groovy correctly, this means that `before` is a in the binding, and accessible from outside code when evaluated with `GroovyShell.evaluate()`.

In the ScriptBase I do the following:

```
class ProductSpecificationBase extends Script {
    def before = null
}
```

This script base may or may not be overridden later on.
Then, in the `Handler`, I'm doing a check for whether a `before` closure is defined in the script:

```
def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.setScriptBaseClass(ScriptBase.class.name)

def shell = GroovyShell()
evaluatedScript = shell.evaluate(new File(thePathToScript))

if (evaluatedScript.before) { 
    theEvaluationOfMyScript.before()
}
```

The code works as expected if the script does contain a `before` closure, but if it doesn't it returns a `MissingPropertyException`. I've had a look at what this means, and it seems that my `before` in the `ScriptBase` isn't considered a property, and all the examples of using these `ScriptBase`s I've found on the internet give examples of using methods. This is not feasible for my use case I'm afraid. How can I ensure that the closure in the `ScriptBase` is considered a property instead of a field(as I am assuming it is now).

To be paraphrase: I would like my code to not execute the `if` block if the script does not contain a `before` closure as well as not having been overridden in an extension of the `ScriptBase`. However, I would like the evaluation of `evaluatedScript.before` to be `false` as it is an empty/null Closure (i.e. it went all the way up to `ScriptBase`, and found the null closure)
I like to avoid a try/catch approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you would basically call the getter for the `before` property.  To check, if there is a method with the name (and params) check with `respondsTo`.  To see, if there is a property at all with that name use `hasProperty` (Thanks @dmahapatro for pointing this out)

```
class X {
    void before() { println 'x' }
}

class Y { }

class Z {
    def before = { println 'z' }
}

def x = new X()
def y = new Y()
def z = new Z()

assert x.respondsTo('before', null)
assert !y.respondsTo('before', null)
assert !z.respondsTo('before', null)

assert !x.hasProperty('before')
assert !y.hasProperty('before')
assert z.hasProperty('before')

x.before()
z.before()
```

Comment: `before` is a closure. So you would have to use `hasProperty` instead. `assert x.hasProperty('before')` and `assert !y.hasProperty('before')` where `def before = { println "hello" }`

Comment: @dmahapatro thanks for the hint.  i have added this too to the answer.

Comment: I thought that since I've got a `before` closure in the ScriptBase I'd still have the property... But this is not the case, and the property is missing, as I've set it to null?

Comment: @kinbiko sorry, I don't follow.  If this anwer misses the point, I gladly remove it, but could you for this case please provde a more complete example (code), to illustrate the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote the problem initially I was quite rushed. I've updated the question now. Hopefully it's clearer now.